# Difference betwee torch.unsqueeze and target.unsqueeze

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am training a simple MLP by computing the MSE and get the following error:

> UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.

The following gives me the right solution
`target = target.unsqueeze(1)` while `torch.unsqueeze(target,1)` does not. The former solution is from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798033/valueerror-target-size-torch-size16-must-be-the-same-as-input-size-torch) and the latter comes from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html)

Why does the latter fix the UserWarning message with the former doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`torch.unsqueeze` **Returns a new tensor** with a dimension of size one inserted at the specified position. That is its not an inplace operation thus you need to assign its output to something. i.e. simply do :

```
target = torch.unsqueeze(target, 1)
```

Otherwise the tensor will remain the same, as you did not store the changes back into it!