# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([1000])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1000, 1]))

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to train my first neural net in pyTorch (I'm not a programmer, just a confused chemist).

The net itself is supposed to take 1064 element vectors and rate them with a float number.

So far I have encountered a variety of errors, ranging from 'float instead of long' to 'Target 1 is out of bounds'. Thus I have redefined the dtypes, corrected the dimensions of the input vector, changed the loss function and now I am stuck in the situation when correcting the current error sets me back to the previous ones.

Which is:

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([1000])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1000, 1]))
```

at the `'loss=loss_calc(outputs, target)'` line.

I tried unsqueezing the label during the DataSet class definition, but this solution sets me back. When I tried to `label = label.view(1,1)`, the resulting error changed to

> Target size (torch.Size([1000, 1, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1000, 1]))

Could anyone please help me figure this out?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rdkit
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, transform=None):
        self.data = pd.read_excel(path)
        self.transform = transform
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        smiles=self.data.at[index, 'smiles']
        mol=Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
        morgan = torch.tensor(list(AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol, 1, nBits=1064)), dtype=torch.float)
        
        label=torch.tensor(self.data.at[index, 'score'], dtype=torch.long)
        
        if self.transform is not None:
            morgan=self.transform(morgan)
        
        return morgan, label

class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1064, 1064)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1064, 1)
        self.act = nn.Tanh()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.act(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

trainSet=dataset(r'C:\Users\BajMic\Peptides\trainingSet.xlsx')
testSet=dataset(r'C:\Users\BajMic\Peptides\testSet.xlsx')

net = Net()
loss_calc = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):
    running_loss=0.0
    for data in DataLoader(trainSet, batch_size=1000, shuffle=True):
        inputs, target = data
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(inputs)
        print(outputs)
        loss = loss_calc(outputs, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %(epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss))
        running_loss = 0.0
print('Finished Training')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Target size (torch.Size(\[16\])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size(\[16, 1\]))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798033/valueerror-target-size-torch-size16-must-be-the-same-as-input-size-torch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with a loss function and having problems with shapes you will usually have an error message of this type:

> Target size (torch.Size([...])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([...]))

*'Target'* refers to the label, the ground-truth, while *'input'* refers to your model's output. In this case, the output is *1000* predictions (you set `batch_size=1000`) of 1 scalar value. Therefore the shape is `(1000, 1)`. This last axis is the one bothering you, since the prediction vector is just a 1D tensor containing 1000 scalars, i.e. `(1000)`.

To solve this you can expand your target tensor with an extra dimension. With [`torch.unsqueeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html):

```
target = target.unsqueeze(-1) # -1 stands for last here equivalent to 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to the problem is mentioned.

There could be a condition where there is a requirement for one-hot labels to be implemented in a machine learning model (required especially in binary classification models). For that purpose, you have to change your single column labels into one-hot encodings. The following code would help you do the same:

```
labels = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(labels)
```