# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([32])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([32, 3]))

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, bert-language-model

I've looked at some explanation.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537991/valueerror-target-size-torch-size1000-must-be-the-same-as-input-size-tor)

But I understand what is going wrong I think, but my error occurs not at the loss. For example the snippet where the error is occurring is the line `outputs = model(**inputs)`.

```py
 # INPUTS
        # Pulling out the inputs in the form of dictionary
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2],
                  }
        # OUTPUTS
        # '**' Unpacking the dictionary stright into the input
        outputs = model(**inputs)

        loss = outputs[0]
        loss_train_total += loss.item()
        loss.backward()           # backpropagation
```

Error I am getting:

```
 File "c:\Users\#####\BERT.py", line 193, in <module>
    outputs = model(**inputs)
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([32])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([32, 3]))
```

Now I know 32 is the batch size, but not sure where this target is. I know it's the label but how do I fix this such that it runs?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I tried one hot encoding the labels like so:

```py
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(train_y.reshape(-1, 1))
train_y = enc.transform(train_y.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

enc.fit(test_y.reshape(-1, 1))
test_y = enc.transform(test_y.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
```

output

```py
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 ...
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

But I still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution that I could find is to expand the dimensions of the 'labels'. I have done this using the following code:

```
labels = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(labels)
```

This would convert your labels list into one-hot encodings. This should match the dimension of the labels and the input.

Comment: Thanks, so basically what the error is saying is the target size is only 1, where as it should be 3 like [1,0,0] as an example?

Comment: Exactly. This was the exact problem in my case.

Comment: So would obviously my dataframe has a column 'labels' that has the 1,0,-1 values, will I need to one hot encode that before splitting data etc.

Comment: You can one-hot encode after splitting. This is actually more preferable!

Comment: So basically the columns will look like ['id','text','positive','neutral','negative'] where positive, neutral and negative are the 3 class labels and will be 1 or 0 respectively?

Comment: Yes. This would be the exact representation

Comment: I tried the above, and it still raises the same error. I changed the 'train_y' and 'test_y' to one hot encoded states i.e. a 2D array. I showed in the Edit of my OP post