# Binary classification - BCELoss and model output size not corresponding

Tags: pytorch

I'm doing a binary classification, hence I used a binary cross entropy loss:

```
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 2])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

My model ends with:

```
    x = self.wave_block6(x)
    x = self.sigmoid(self.fc(x))
    return x.squeeze()
```

I tried removing the squeeze, but to no avail. My batch size is 64. It seems like I'm doing something simple wrong here. Is my model giving 1 output and BCE loss expecting 2 inputs? Which loss should I use then?

Comment: ur model should hav single output.....

Comment: try to include more info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Target size (torch.Size(\[16\])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size(\[16, 1\]))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798033/valueerror-target-size-torch-size16-must-be-the-same-as-input-size-torch)

Answer (score 1):

Binary Cross-Entropy Loss  (BCELoss) is used for binary classification tasks. Therefore if N is your batch size, your model output should be of shape `[64, 1]` and your labels must be of shape `[64]`.Therefore just squeeze your output at the 2nd dimension and pass it to the loss function -
Here is a minimal working example

```
import torch
a = torch.randn((64, 1))
b = torch.randn((64))
loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()

b = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(b)) # just to create some labels
a = torch.sigmoid(a).squeeze(1)
l = loss(a, b)
```

Update - Basing on the conversation in the comments, focal loss can be defined as follows -

```
class focalLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.25, gamma=3):
        super(focalLoss, self).__init__()
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.gamma = gamma

    def forward(self, pred_logits: torch.Tensor, target: torch.Tensor):
        batch_size = pred_logits.shape[0]
        pred = pred.view(batch_size, -1)
        target = target.view(batch_size, -1)
        pred = pred_logits.sigmoid()
        ce = F.binary_cross_entropy(pred_logits, target, reduction='none')
        alpha = target * self.alpha + (1. - target) * (1. - self.alpha)
        pt = torch.where(target == 1, pred, 1 - pred)
        return alpha * (1. - pt) ** self.gamma * ce
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Perhaps my colab is not refreshing the code from my local drive. Also I noticed in the training this is called: loss = criterion(output, target.long())

Comment: Both target and input should be of type float for BCELoss, so you would get that error later once this error is solved, please note that the CrossEntropy loss function takes the target of type long, so maybe the original code was written for CrossEntropy loss

Comment: @dorien, coming back to the issue at hand, could you please tell me your label shape(i.e your target) and your model output shape? You mentioned in the question that it is ` 64, 2` but you are using BCELoss, for a binary classification problem you only need to output one value, not 2

Comment: I'm using FocalLoss in the original loss, was trying to adapt to BCELoss. Let me run to print the shapes (sorry it takes a while, big dataset), trying to run local at them moment.

Comment: Also, I would be adding a focal loss definition you can use out of the box

Comment: Any suggestions for the out of the box focal loss? I'll check the rest of the shape shortly.

Comment: What do you mean by suggestions?, It cannot be used for multiclass problems, you would require cross-entropy loss for that

Comment: I just have one class to predict really: yes on no. 

I just checked, even with squeeze(1), the output of my model is (64,2) instead of (64,1_: 

        x = self.wave_block6(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(self.fc(x))
        return x.squeeze(1)

Comment: Could you please post your complete model definition, maybe the size problem lies there

Comment: I was able to solve it in the training by putting: target = F.one_hot(target.squeeze(), num_classes=self.num_classes).to(self.device)   Just hope the cuda moving there won't slow down the model.